# High data rate on HF & MF bands

Tags: antenna, hf, propagation, rf-power

Is it possible to transfer data at a high rate, like 1-2 Mbps, on 0.5 - 30 MHz?

From Shannon's Theorem, with a bandwidth of just 300 kHz it is possible to reach 1.5 Mbps.

I want to use these bands because of longer ranges and lower losses in urban areas, but I do not know why these bands are not used for Wi-Fi connections. What is the problem with operating like this?

Comment: Can you please post your actual derivation of the 1.5 Mbps channel capacity? Note that Shannon-Hartley capacity theorem gives a theoretical upper bound.

Comment: for HQ vedios for example .

Comment: In addition to what other answers have said, the natural noise floor is higher at lower frequencies, and propagation is more unpredictable at HF and below.

Answer (score 4):

There are many reasons not to use low frequencies such as below 30 MHz. Here are just a few:

1) It is prohibited by law. These frequencies are assigned to other services. 2.4GHz is a shared service... Even your microwave oven cooks there.

2) They need large antennas to function. The shortest antenna at 30 Mhz, which still is effective, is about 5 meters long (while at 2.4GHz it only needs 6-7 cm).

3) Shannon's limit isn't (a limit, I mean): the formula $C=B\log_2(1+\frac{S}{N})$ just says that you can send more info over the same bandwidth if you improve the $\frac{S}{N}$ ratio.

4) Then, you should realize that if you want to be at Shannon's C rate, you have to have the channel for yourself. No other users can use the same frequency. If you realize that 2.4 GHz is a jungle with probably 100s of simultaneous users...

So, if you want to improve your channel capacity (C), you should concentrate on improving the S/N ratio, which is much easier to do at 2.4 or 5.2 GHz than at 0-30 MHz

Comment: I want increase my wifi range up to 30-60 km at heavy urban areas.... wich it is impossible at 5 GHz , 2,4GHz or even 900 MHz !

Comment: Well, I think you will have to either install a repeater (most APs can configured as such) somewhere, or, probably the most economical/reliable way, use the internet.

Comment: internet cant be used for mobile receiver

Comment: Haven't you heard about WiFi?

Comment: I talking about HF wifi

Comment: I think it would be helpful @abduoman11 to understand your particular application a bit better.

Comment: just I want my own system

Answer (score 4):

There are several reasons the low bands are not used for high data throughput:

1. The problem is at HF frequencies, a 300kHz bandwidth is a lot of spectrum. At MF frequencies it's a whole lot of spectrum.

   1a. If you look at [this spectrum chart](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/United_States_Frequency_Allocations_Chart_2003_-_The_Radio_Spectrum.jpg) you will see that 300kHz covers more that 10 assigned services at MF and covers most of 4 services at HF.
2. From a legal standpoint (most countries have laws governing spectrum usage) you would not be authorized to transmit over such a wide chunk of spectrum.

   2a. To be legal you would have to lease the spectrum and even if you could get the governing agency to lease all that spectrum to you, you couldn't afford it.
3. If you decided to ignore the legal aspect and forge ahead(see point 4 however), remember MF frequencies travel great distances via ground-wave propagation and HF frequencies bounce of the ionosphere and travel around the world.  A 300kHz signal would cause a lot of people interference. Someone would hunt you down and stick a pin in your COAX. [tic]
4. You would have to design and build a transmitter/receiver and antenna system capable of transmitting/receiving such a broad signal on those frequency bands which would be impractical.

I hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: While I was typing this I got interrupted (took me an hour to get back to the post) and another answer was posted in the meantime which basically covers what I said, and covered the S/N ratio.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I couldn't figure out how to indent the sub-paragraphs.

Comment: but for example the 1.8 - 2 MHz  is  200 KHz , may be be enough for 0.5 - 1 Mbps .

Comment: Yes, it may be, depending on conditions (S/N), but you are using that entire segment of spectrum all to yourself and that would be illegal for one, and frowned upon by all the users of that chunk of spectrum.  Look at it this way, each 'band' has 10 times more bandwidth than the previous band.  So in order to do HQ video the lowest band that would have enough bandwidth to reasonably support this activity would be the UHF band.

Comment: The other problem with your example is designing a transceiver/antenna system to handle such a wide transmission at such a low frequency, it would be impractical.

Comment: A little more information on a frequency chart is at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio_frequency_allocations#Table_of_Amateur_MF_and_HF_Bandplans